# Exporting time series data of multipoints in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have created three points of land surface temperature. I want to export the time series result in three different variable names.

```js
// Import country boundaries feature collection.

var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');

// here is the three points of land surface temperature

var features = [
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(14.5, -15)),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(14.8, -15.1)),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(14.9, -15.2))
];

var points = ee.FeatureCollection(features);
Map.addLayer(points);

// Import LST image collection.

var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/MOD11A2');
var start = ee.Date('2001-01-01');
var dateRange = ee.DateRange(start, start.advance(15, 'year'));
var mod11a2 = modis.filterDate(dateRange);

// Select only the 1km day LST data band.

var modLSTday = mod11a2.select('LST_Day_1km');
var modLSTc = modLSTday.map(function(img) {
return img
.multiply(0.02)
.subtract(273.15)
.copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start']);
});

// Time series at the identified points

// "Please help here in this point"
```

The export result looks like the attached picture.[image: ][1]]

Comment: what do you mean by `Export`? To me, the expected result is not clear

Comment: Yes. I want to export. Many thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Export.table` function, where as this export can be done to Google Drive with the use of the code `Export.table.toDrive()` in detail `Export.table.toDrive(collection, description, folder, fileNamePrefix, fileFormat, selectors)`

Ex -

```
Export.table.toDrive({collection: features,description:'vectorsToDriveExample', fileFormat: 'KML'});
```

[image: Details of the code]

-or-

do export the table to Assets folder with `Export.table.toAsset()`

[image: Asset Folder]

-but-

before all these you have to create a variable (table/list/array/dictionary) **containing the data** to export which I am not finding with in your code.